# How to write list to file?

Tags: list, haskell, io

I am trying:

```
import System.IO
saveArr = do
    outh <- openFile "test.txt" WriteMode
    hPutStrLn outh [1,2,3]
    hClose outh
```

but it doesn't works... output:

> No instance for (Num Char) arising from the literal `1'

**EDIT**
OK `hPrint` works with ints but what about float number in array? `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hPutStrLn` can only print strings. Perhaps you want `hPrint`?

```
hPrint outh [1,2,3]
```

Comment: One more question: what if there are float number? `[1.2, 2.0, 3.0]` ?

Comment: @MMM: The same. `hPrint` can print any Show instances.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays, Lists and Strings exists only in imagination of programmer and as a term in some languages.

File is a sequence of bytes, so when you want to write something to it you should encode that imaginary String/List/Array into sequence of bytes (by `show` or by something from `Storable` etc).
As well terminal is a sequence of bytes which is encoded representation of actions needed to show something to user.

You have many ways to encode. You can make CSV representation of array by `foldr (\a b -> a (',' : b)) "\n" (map shows [1,2,3])` or you may want to print it `show [1,2,3]`

Comment: For me `hPutStrLn stdout (show [1,2,3])` gives the right result. Check that you use `show`, but not `shows` and that you use it from `Text.Show` module.

Answer (score 1):

derive Binary for your type, then write the data in binnary form using 'encodeFile' from the Data.Binary package. This is similar to writing the data out as a bytestring.